# Why isn't scala.util.Success.apply infinitely recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion, try-catch

[`scala.util.Success`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Success) doesn't have an `apply` method but inherits the one from [`scala.util.Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try) (AFAIK). But all `scala.util.Try.apply` does is call `Success.apply` surrounded by a `try catch` block. How is this not infinitely recursive and how does this ever trigger the `catch` block?

Comment: Ok, I see that the parameter to Try.apply is a function, therefore you are evaluating it; but in the case of Failure.apply the parameter is a Throwable and I cannot track down any implicit conversion between Throwable and Function. Especially since Throwable is actually the java class, java.lang.Throwable.

Comment: `Try.apply` is a call by name function, as the comment states. So `Try(mayThrowException)` does not get evaluated outside `Try` but inside the `try Success(mayThrowException)` statement inside `Try` object, And `Sucess` is a case class that evaluate argument eagerly, `mayThrowExecption` get job done here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, scala's `Success` is a **case class** that inherits `abstract class Try`.
So the apply method is a built-in method generated by scala compiler, not inherited from the object `Try`.

Source https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L225